# 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'compute_loss'

Tags: gensim

I want to know the loss for my w2v model and I upgrade `gensim` to the latest version, but still can't use the argument `compute_loss`, am I miss something??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No released version of gensim (through 2.2.0 of June 2017) yet has that feature. It is a work-in-progress in the `develop` branch, which should appear in a future release.